# How to map query result to a list of object in dapper

Tags: c#, dapper

I have a model class like:

```
 public class PageEditDto
 {
    public Guid PageId { get; set; }
    public string? Header { get; set; }
    public string? Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
    public int? PageTypeId { get; set; }
    public int PublishPlaceId { get; set; }
    public List<int>? PublishPlacesList { get; set; }
    public int? SubjectTypeId { get; set; }

    public Guid? ApprovedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ApprovedAt { get; set; }

    public string? PageIconPath { get; set; }
    public int? ReadQuantity { get; set; }
    
    public string? MainImage { get; set; }
    public List<string>? ImageGallery { get; set; }
}
```

In the result object I have several ImageGallery row connected to the PageId i.e, there are multiple records having same pageId returning from the sql. I want to map these to "List<ImageGallery" property in my model class.
Is there any efficient way to do it other than creating a loop and match the records having the same PageId etc.

Comment: Can you edit your question to show the SQL and sample results?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GroupBy` on the results to project your model. Here is an example assuming `result` is what you get back from the Dapper query, `PublishPlace` is what you named the column containing the PublishPlacesList values and `Image` is what you named the column containing the ImageGallery values.

```
// group by all of the "flat" properties
var pageEdits = result.GroupBy(p => new
    {
        p.PageId, p.Header, p.Content, p.StartDate, p.Endate, p.PageTypeId,
        p.PublishPlaceId, p.SubjectTypeId, p.ApprovedBy, p.ApprovedAt,
        p.PageIconPath, p.ReadQuantity, p.MainImage
    }).Select(m => new PageEditDto
        {
            PageId = m.Key.PageId,
            Header = m.Key.Header,
            Content = m.Key.Content,
            StartDate = m.Key.StartDate,
            Endate = m.Key.Endate,
            PageTypeId = m.Key.PageTypeId,
            PublishPlaceId = m.Key.PublishPlaceId,
            SubjectTypeId = m.Key.SubjectTypeId,
            ApprovedBy = m.Key.ApprovedBy,
            ApprovedAt = m.Key.ApprovedAt,
            PageIconPath = m.Key.PageIconPath,
            ReadQuantity = m.Key.ReadQuantity,
            MainImage = m.Key.MainImage,
            PublishPlacesList = m.PublishPlace.ToList(),
            ImageGallery = m.Image.ToList()
        }).ToList();
```